# Formatting of TypeScript index signatures object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I'm using TypeScript with Angular 1.5 and the Angular 1.5 type definition however I can't figure out how to define the bindings within an Angular component.

The definition file contains the following for bindings

```
interface IComponentOptions {
  ...
  bindings?: {[binding: string]: string};
  ...
}
```

But how do I wright the actual Javascript object?

```
.component('myComponent', {
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: MyController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindings: {
    one: '<',
    two: '<'
  }
});
```

The above gives me

```
Type '{ one: string; two: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [binding: string]: string; }'.
```

All replies are appreciated!

Comment: how about "one": "<"?

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type '{ one: string; two: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [binding: string]: string; }'

Probably using an old version of TypeScript. Works fine in the latest compiler.

```
interface IComponentOptions {
    bindings?: { [binding: string]: string };
}

var componentOptions: IComponentOptions = {
    bindings: {
        one: '<',
        two: '<'
    }
};
```

[You can try it here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IComponentOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%09bindings%3F%3A%20%7B%20%5Bbinding%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20componentOptions%3A%20IComponentOptions%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09bindings%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09one%3A%20'%3C'%2C%0D%0A%09%09two%3A%20'%3C'%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B)